# num_rows and count() mismatch - php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result->num_rows; //2 is value produced
```

BUT

```
$tagResult =  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
echo count($tagResult); //1 is the value produced
```

Isn't it suppose to produce the same number of values?

Comment: mysqli_fetc_array Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row  (one row)  http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.

So it only fetches 1 row.  To get both/all you need to fetch all rows in a loop:

```
while($tagResult[] =  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {}
echo count($tagResult);
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise response.

Comment: When I ran your solution, the values returned had the same index. Is that suppose to happen?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, numeric index?  If so then yes, `0` is the first column, `1` is the second etc... in that row.  If you want column names use `MYSQLI_ASOCC` instead of `MYSQLI_NUM` or use the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function.

Comment: I mean as in [0]=> 1,  [0]=>2

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array` will fetch one row at a time, wherever the pointer for the result currently is. When you first get the result, the pointer is at the first row. When you call mysqli_fetch_array, it will grab record 1 (where the pointer is) then increment the pointer to the next record. When you call it again, it will grab record 2, and so on.

If you have more than one row returned, you will need to loop through the results, calling mysqli_fetch_array on each row. Because mysqli_fetch_array returns null when there are no more rows, you can use a simple while loop:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result->num_rows; //2 is value produced

$count = 0;
while ($tagResult = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    print_r($tagResult); // Output each row
    $count ++;
}
echo $count; //outputs 2
```